# I have a date format in a variable.How can i convert that variable date to another format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date format in a variable. the variable date format is (var kdsDteformat =4-november-2014). now i want to change this format to 11-04-2014 how can i make it possible? And my variable date format is dynamic

```
var kdsDteformat = 4-november-2014;
```

Answer (score -2):

how about doing something like:

```
var kdsDteformat = '4-november-2014';
var parts = kdsDteFormat.split('-');
var d = new Date(parts[1].substr(0,3) + ' ' + parts[0] + ',' + parts[2])
```

And now you have a regular Date object that you can format as you want, for example

```
console.log([d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDay(), d.getFullYear()].join('-'));
```

Comment: then how can i alert the new date?

Comment: `new Date('4-november-2014')` will give you an invalid date in at least some browsers, so then `d.getMonth()` and so forth will return nan.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work on all browsers, the new version works as it constructs a date string that can be parsed

Comment: any solution for this ques??